# Matrix file uploads, only first file being uploaded

Tags: safecracker, matrix

I am trying to customise a matrix field, for safecracker use, to customise the look of file (image) uploads.

I  have the following code http://jsfiddle.net/sanxL/ in my safecracker form, and it seems to produce the rows correctly, however when i send the form, only the first field has the attached file (photos in this case)

Anything obvious wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too worry, found out what I was doing wrong! Forgot to include the hidden `<input type="hidden" name="walk_images[row_order][]"
value="row_new_0">` within the div that was being recreated.

All good now.